# How to get access to parent's object handles?

Tags: c++, c, winapi

I have ParentProcess.exe which has the following code. It creates a file and fils it with a simple character of 1 then it creates a new process which is called ChildProcess.exe. This ChildProcess created with bIheritance flag true. I wanted it to have the ability to get access to the objects of the parent.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES process_sa;
    process_sa.nLength = sizeof(process_sa);
    process_sa.bInheritHandle = TRUE;
    process_sa.lpSecurityDescriptor = 0;

    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES thread_sa;
    thread_sa.nLength = sizeof(thread_sa);
    thread_sa.bInheritHandle = TRUE;
    thread_sa.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;

    HANDLE hFileCreated = CreateFile("e:\\Sample.txt", GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_READ, &process_sa, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0);
    if (hFileCreated == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        printf("File doesn't created.");
        return 1;
    }

    char c = '1';
    DWORD w;
    WriteFile(hFileCreated, &c, 1, &w, 0);

    STARTUPINFO sinfo;
    ZeroMemory(&sinfo, sizeof(sinfo));
    sinfo.cb = sizeof(sinfo);

    PROCESS_INFORMATION pinfo;
    ZeroMemory(&pinfo, sizeof(pinfo));

    if (CreateProcess(0, "ChildProcess.exe", &process_sa, &thread_sa, TRUE, 0, 0, 0, &sinfo, &pinfo))
        printf("done.");
    else
        printf("failed.");

    CloseHandle(pinfo.hThread);
    CloseHandle(pinfo.hProcess);


    return 0;
}
```

ChildProcess.exe had the following code which I wanted it can get access to the handle of the file which is created by the parent process but when it gets run it shows the address of 0XFFFFFFFF. Where is the problem. The ChildProcess code:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <process.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    HANDLE hFileCreatedInheritance = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    _stscanf_s(L"e:\\Sample.txt", _T("%p"), &hFileCreatedInheritance);
    printf("The handle of the file is %p.\n", hFileCreatedInheritance);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Read the documentation for CreateFile, paying particular attention to dwShareMode.  It refers to what will happen if a second process attempts to open the file when the original process has it open.

Comment: @thurizas that only applies if both processes call `CreateFile`, which is not the case in this situation.

Comment: Um...that is the point.  `CreateFile` doesn't deal with sharing handles across processes.  To access the file, the OP would have to call `CreateFile `in the child process as well as the parent.  I am unsure if `CreateProcess`'s arguments allow for the sharing of file handles.  (I'm fairly sure that `fork` does).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In parent process:**

Convert your handle to a string before inserting it into the text file:

```
DWORD w;
std::stringstream streamAdr;
streamAdr << hFileCreated;  
std::string strAddr = streamAdr.str(); 

WriteFile(hFileCreated, strAddr.c_str(), strAddr.size(), &w, 0);
```

**In child process:**

```
string sLine;
ifstream infile("G:\\Sample.txt");
if (infile.good())
{
    getline(infile, sLine); // Get first line containing handle of file
    infile.close(); 

    unsigned int i = stoi(sLine.c_str(), 0, 16); // Convert hexadecimal string

    hFileCreatedInheritance = (HANDLE) i; // cast to a HANDLE
    printf("The handle of the file is %p.\n", hFileCreatedInheritance);
}
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Question:**
 what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: You are using `ostream::operator<<(void*)` to write the value of `hFileCreated` to the file, so why wouldn't you use `istream::operator>>(void*&)` to read it into `hFileCreatedInheritance`? You don't need to use `getline()` and `stoi()`

Comment: @rem: That will fail in case child and parent have different bitness. Of course, the solution offered in this answer doesn't address this case either. In fact, it's worse in that it fails in case the child process is a 64-bit process, and exhibits undefined behavior in case the child process is a 32-bit (or 64-bit) process.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Indeed, it's simpler with your alternative

Comment: @IInspectable "*That will fail in case child and parent have different bitness*" - [no, it won't](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/interprocess-communication): "*64-bit versions of Windows use 32-bit handles for interoperability. When sharing a handle between 32-bit and 64-bit applications, only the lower 32 bits are significant, so it is safe to truncate the handle (when passing it from 64-bit to 32-bit) or sign-extend the handle (when passing it from 32-bit to 64-bit). **Handles that can be shared include ... file handles**.*"

Comment: @rem: Regardless of the number of significant bits in a `HANDLE`, a `void*` has a different size for 32-bit and 64-bit builds. Writing a 32-bit `void*` and attempting to read a 64-bit `void*` is not a meaningful operation. Sure, you can transfer `HANDLE`s between processes of different bitness, but you cannot do it as you propose, or this answer.

Comment: @IInspectable yes, you can. Writing a 32bit `void*` value representing a `HANDLE` and then reading the value into a 64bit `void*` representing another `HANDLE` is perfectly safe. *MSDN specifically states as much*. The written value will populate only the lower 32 bits, the higher 32 bits will be either zero-extended or sign-extended depending on the read, but still ignored by the OS either way.

Comment: @rem: Indeed, the information in the MSDN is accurate. The suggestion in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61021752/how-to-get-access-to-parents-object-handles/61022326#comment107960206_61022326) simply doesn't implement the requirements. The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/interprocess-communication) is explicit: *"\[...\] sign-extend the handle (when passing it from 32-bit to 64-bit)"*. There's no mention of bits getting ignored by the OS.

Comment: @IInspectable "*There's no mention of bits getting ignored by the OS*" - yes, there is. That is exactly what the statement "only the lower 32 bits are significant" means in MSDN's documentation. The doc says that "it is safe to ... sign-extend the handle (when passing it from 32-bit to 64-bit)." That does not mean that sign extension is required, because it is not.